# How do I back up images with limited disk space?

Tags: backup, disk-space, tar

I'm in a scenario where I have one 500GB hard drive and about 400GB of images I want to tar. I obviously won't have enough disk space, but I don't mind getting rid of the images as they are added to the archive.

Is there any way to add each image to a tarball and delete the image afterwards so that disk space constraints aren't a problem?

Comment: Typically images are almost incompressible. Why do you want to tar them in first place? Why not simply storing them in one or more directories and remove old images when space runs out?

Comment: I just want to archive them so I can send them to a different server. I don't care much for the compression, if any

Comment: And why does copying them to a folder not work then?

Comment: `tar -cvf images.tar my_directory --remove-files`

Answer (score 0):

If you want send them to a different server then just do it - using either FTP, ssh, windows shared folders or any other available transport.

If the direct connection between the old and the new servers isn't available then you have to use something as an intermediate: starting from external drive to FTP space for rent.